# Java 8 streams - How to extract all objects inside a map of maps to a new map?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map of maps

```
siteId -> (AppName -> App)
```

I want to iterate all of the Apps in the inner map and create a new map of

```
(appId -> App)
```

I do it without stream

```
Map<String, App> result = new HashMap<>();

siteIdToAppNameToAppMap.forEach((siteId, map) ->
   map.forEach((appName, app) ->
      result.put(app.token, app)
   )
);
```

How do I do it with stream?

Comment: Hint: to convert nested loops, you generally need flatMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
siteIdToAppNameToAppMap.values()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
   .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(App::getToken, Function.identity())
   );
```

We will need to use [Stream#flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to extract `App` from nested map. So `stream().values()` will give us `Stream<Map<AppName,App>>` now we need to transform it into `Stream<App>` using flatMap:

```
Stream<Map<AppName,App>> -> flatMap ->  Stream<App>
```

and after is we can finally collect to a new `Map<AppId,App>`

Comment: nitpick - this overload of the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector doesn't guarantee on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned. Although, for now, it's returning a `HashMap` tomorrow it could be returning a different type of map. assuming the OP is doing this for production code and cares about the type of map returned, it's better to explicitly specify that you want a `HashMap` instance, not only for a guarantee of the type returned.

Comment: but also documents to the user what type of map is being returned.

Comment: just thought, I'd mention this as the OP is doing`Map<String, App> result = new HashMap<>();` in their code example snippet.

Comment: Or `.map(Map::values).flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different variant to @Anton Balaniuc's answer.

```
Map<String, App> resultSet = 
           siteIdToAppNameToAppMap.values()
                                  .stream()
                                  .map(Map::values)
                                  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(App::getToken, 
                                            Function.identity(), (left, right) -> {  
                                       throw new RuntimeException("duplicate key");
                                             },
                                                   HashMap::new));
```

This solution creates a stream from the `siteIdToAppNameToAppMap` map values, which we then perform a `map` operation to the map values yielding a `Stream<Collection<App>>` and then `flatMap` will collapse all the nested `Stream<Collection<App>>` to a `Stream<App>` and then finally the `toMap` collector will return a `Collector` that accumulates the elements into a Map whose keys are the return value of `App::getToken` and values are the return value of `Function.identity()`.

The function `(left, right) -> {  throw new RuntimeException("duplicate key");}` above is the merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key. in this particular case, you don't need it but it's only there so we can use this overload of the `toMap` collector which then allows us to specify that we specifically want a `HashMap` instance.

All, the other `toMap` overloads don't guarantee on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned.

*Note* - if you're not expecting duplicate keys then throwing an exception, as shown above, is the way to go as it indicates there's a problem as opposed to doing something else. However, if in the case of a duplicate key you want to return a value then you can simply change the merge function to `(left, right) -> left` or `(left, right) -> right` depending on what you want.