# Merge ArrayList of Integers by specific logic

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, merge

I have ArrayList containing many instances of my simple model class *User* containing just 2 fields:

```
@Data
public class User {
    private String email;
    private ArrayList<Integer> lists; 
}
```

I'm inserting into *lists* field integer values, always **1** or **0**. 
Having many objects of *User* class, some of them are duplicates because they have the same *email* address but different *lists*.

I need to merge duplicates of *Users* into one object of *User*, also taking care of *lists* field.

```
User user1 = new User('email@gmail.com', Arrays.asList(0, 1, 0, 1, 1)); 
User user2 = new User('email@gmail.com', Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0, 1, 1));
User user3 = new User('email@gmail.com', Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 1));
/* merge duplicated objects into one */
User mergedUser = new User('email@gmail.com', Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 1, 1));
```

I'm having difficulties implementing logic for merging many *lists* into one.
Logic behind it's not complicated: whenever there was **1**, put **1** in merged list. Having many lists with **0** and just one **1**, results in value **1** in final, merged list.

What approach I should take to implement this logic for merging lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
List<User> finalList = new ArrayList<>(users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getEmail, Function.identity(), (user1, user2) -> {
            List<Integer> l1 = user1.getLists();
            List<Integer> l2 = user2.getLists();
            List<Integer> merge = IntStream.range(0, l1.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> (l1.get(i) == 0 && l2.get(i) == 0) ? 0 : 1)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new User(user1.getEmail(), merge);
        })).values());
```

Answer (score 2):

As of JDK8, you can use the `toMap` method as follows to accomplish your task.

```
Collection<User> result = 
        list.stream()
           .collect(toMap(User::getEmail,
                   Function.identity(),
                   (l, r) -> {
                       List<Integer> firstList = l.getList();
                       List<Integer> secondList = r.getList();
                     IntStream.range(0, firstList.size())
                              .forEach(i -> firstList.set(i, Math.max(firstList.get(i), secondList.get(i))));
                            return l;
                   })).values();
```

you can further make this more readable by extracting the merging logic into a helper method:

```
private static User apply(User l, User r) {
        List<Integer> firstList = l.getList();
        List<Integer> secondList = r.getList();
        IntStream.range(0, firstList.size())
                .forEach(i -> firstList.set(i, Math.max(firstList.get(i), secondList.get(i))));
        return l;
}
```

then you can do:

```
Collection<User> result = list.stream()
                .collect(toMap(User::getEmail, Function.identity(), Main::apply))
                .values();
```

where `Main` refers to the class containing the `apply` method.

---

Note the important thing here is the merge function (`(l, r) -> { ...`), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353493/java-8-streams-how-to-extract-all-objects-inside-a-map-of-maps-to-a-new-map/49353620#49353620) that explains a little bit about the merge function.

You may want to look into [my other posts](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&biw=1280&bih=625&ei=dnoGXJHVJejDgAb5mbbAAg&q=Aomine%20%22toMap%22%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=Aomine%20%22toMap%22%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l3.0.0..2075...0.0..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.5S9sGKi92ZA) using `toMap` collectors to get familiar with it and [ofcourse the API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

Answer (score 1):

The value of List is always 0 or 1, I recommend to use long or long[] instead of ArrayList

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
  private String email;
  private long flags;

  public static long merge(long... flags) {
    long result = 0;
    for (long flag : flags) {
      result = result | flag;
    }
    return result;
  }


  // test
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    User user1 = new User("email@gmail.com", Long.valueOf("1000000000000101",2));
    User user2 = new User("email@gmail.com", Long.valueOf("0000111100000101",2));
    User user3 = new User("email@gmail.com", Long.valueOf("0000000010110101",2));
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(merge(user1.flags, user2.flags, user3.flags)));
    // result is 1000111110110101
  }
}
```

If the amount of flags is bigger than 32, using long[] to save more flags;

Comment: I am unable ti understand how would this give the `mergedUser` as shown by OP?

Comment: User mergedUser  = new User("email@gmail.com", merge(user1.flags, user2.flags, user3.flags));